# Is there possibility to add ExtraVoice Commands to Voice Guidance which is running from heremaps?

Tags: here-api

Is there possibility to add Extra Voice Commands to Voice Guidance which is running from here maps?
-like Turn Right (From Here maps)  something like- I want (Stop After turn Right)

Answer (score 0):

NMAAudioManager is the central class that is used by SDK for iOS to modify the application AVAudioSession and play audio. It is the interface that the NMANavigationManager uses to play audio feedback such as voice instructions. You can also use NMAAudioManager to change whether hardware keys directly control HERE SDK volume, and also use it to set volume as a factor relative to the user's device volume.

The NMAAudioManager contains a queue of audio output objects. You can add to this queue by calling playOutput: with NMAAudioFileOutput, NMATTSAudioOutput, or your own NMAAudioOutput implementation. You can also use NMAAudioManager methods such as clearQueue, skipCurrentOutput, and stopOutputAndClearQueue to manage audio output in this queue.

Please refer below link for detailed implementation : 
developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/dev_guide/topics/audio-management.html

Comment: For Android How can we do?